# CardLayout didn't display JPanel

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, cardlayout

I'm doing a form for a database and I want to use the CardLayout.
I explain the situation : the user have two choices : either he connects to his accoun or either he's new and he need to create an account.
I've a first panel with the form and an another for a test (in which I set the background at the color Black for to see the changement when the user clicks on the button New). When I launch the main program, I've just the window with the title and nothing else. Or it's not what I want, the first step of my application is to display the form. So if anyone can explain me where is my error, I take it :)

```
public class Accueil extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private CardLayout l = new CardLayout();
    private JPanel main = new JPanel(l);
    private JPanel change = new JPanel();
    private JPanel home = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JPanel title = new JPanel();
    private JPanel login = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JPanel login_title = new JPanel();
    private JPanel login_info = new JPanel();
    private JPanel copyright = new JPanel();
    private JLabel welcome = new JLabel("TEST");
    private JLabel connexion = new JLabel("Connexion");
    private JLabel mail = new JLabel("Mail : "); 
    private JTextField input_mail = new JTextField();
    private JLabel mdp = new JLabel("Password : ");
    private JTextField input_mdp = new JTextField();
    private JLabel who = new JLabel ("Are you a  : ");
    private JRadioButton client = new JRadioButton("Client", true);
    private JRadioButton developpeur = new JRadioButton("Developer", false);
    private ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    private JButton ok = new JButton("Login");
    private JButton annule = new JButton("Cancel");
    private JButton inscription = new JButton("New ?");
    private JLabel align = new JLabel("");

    public Accueil() {

        init_title();
        init_login();
        add_button();
        organize_frame();
        inscription.addActionListener(this);
        main.add(home, "Home");
        main.add(change, "Change");
        l.show(main, "Home");
        change.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setTitle("test");
        this.setSize(600,600);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        l.show(main, "Change");
    }

    private void organize_frame() { 
        home.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        home.add(login, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        home.add(copyright, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void init_title() { 
        welcome.setFont(build_font(35));
        welcome.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20,0,0,0));
        title.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,80));
        title.add(welcome);
    }

    private void init_login() {
        setConnexion();
        user_input();
        align.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(215,50));
        organize_button();
        login.add(login_title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        login.add(login_info, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private void setConnexion() {
        connexion.setFont(build_font(30));
        connexion.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20,0,0,0));
        login_title.add(connexion);
        login_title.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,100));
    }

    private void user_input() {
        who.setFont(build_font(25));
        mail.setFont(build_font(25));
        mail.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,120,0,0));
        mdp.setFont(build_font(25));
        input_mdp.setFont(build_font(25));
        input_mail.setFont(build_font(25));
        input_mail.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,40));
        input_mdp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,40));
        who.setFont(build_font(20));
        client.setFont(build_font(20));
        developpeur.setFont(build_font(21));
        login_info.add(who);
        login_info.add(client);
        login_info.add(developpeur);
        login_info.add(mail);
        login_info.add(input_mail);
        login_info.add(mdp);
        login_info.add(input_mdp);
        login_info.add(align);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Where do you add the CardLayout-using JPanel, main, to anything?

Answer: You don't. To have it work, it must be added to a component that leads eventually to a top level window. It must be displayed in order to allow it to show its "cards".

Comment: @user1086267: you're welcome. When running into problems like these, try to simplify your code to the bare minimum to try to get to the essence of the problem. This way you will likely see the problem and its solution at a glance, or if not, will be able to post simple small code that compiles and runs and that we can use to help you solve your issue.